# Magento CE 1.9 - Out of Stock Product Options still display in Config Product Dropdown

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Interesting issue with a Magento 1.9 store, configurable products that have "Out of Stock" Options are still offering the options within the Product Option dropdown, but when selected and added to the cart, the user is notified "This Product is out of Stock" and it is not added to the cart.

How can I stop "Out of Stock" Options from being offered in the option dropdown?
In my research on the topic, it sounds like this is supposed to be Magento's default setup, and many code mods are available for creating my scenario, but I have not modified any Magento core code.

System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Display Out of Stock Products == "No", but these options are still displaying in the Product Option Dropdown.

I have noticed that the Configurable Option Products are all listing either 1 or 0 for inventory quantity, and all products default to Store config for Inventory Management.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in a template that ignores this "rule". Can you please provide us code from that template?

Comment: Are you hoping for the code from the phtml file that generates that dropdown?

Comment: Thank you for opting to assist me Martin Hucko, I was able to determine the issue was in fact caused by some custom code that allowed a 3rd party to upload inventory statuses for products. I'll add an answer explaining it further.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this post in the future, I resolved this after finding another developer had written a custom CRON that ran nightly to update inventory numbers that a 3rd party FTP'ed directly into the site. The CRON was broken, therefore the inventory numbers were not getting updated, and the product re-index in that CRON was not firing. Always check your inventory numbers and re-index! :)